# How to prevent SQL Injection on PDO::exec

Tags: php, pdo, sqlsrv

I guess the easiest way to prevent sql injection on PDO::Query which take arguments from the user is to use PDO::prepare and PDO::execute. However in my case I have an insert statement which takes a param from user. For this purpose I'm using PDO::exec. Below is not the exact code.

```
$db = new PDO("Connection String to connect to MSSQL");
$rowsAffected = $db->exec("Insert into MyTable (UserParam) Values($userParam)");
```

How can I prevent an sql injection on this?

Comment: you can use prepare with insert statements as well. You could use `PDO::quote` for this, but even [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) advises to use prepared statements instead.

Comment: Don't use `exec()` here. `prepare()/execute()` the INSERT statement with a paramter for `:userParam`.